# Looking to provide remote access to a single PC but *only* its web browser?

Tags: browser, remote-desktop, kiosk

Essentially I would like to be able to navigate to some custom domain that I own, log in to some basic front end, and then have access via a Remote Access Tool to my Linux computer (which would only have open a web browser). I would like to also restrict any accessing parties to only being able to use the web browser (and even then, not be able to change the size of the window, close the browser, etc).

I think I can accomplish all of this except restricting what the parties can do once they are in the Remote Access "Portal", and candidly I don't know where to start.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This might sound stupid, bit honest question: that is just a browser, right, which shows some web frontend. Why not, instead of offering the remote screen to your user after authentication, offer the web frontend for their local browser to display locally? Surely someone with a remote desktop client installed also has a browser?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I should have been more clear in my question / provided more details.

The reason I can't do what you have proposed is because the machine that they will be accessing will be hosting a webapp that they can then use (remotely). It is complicated, but the short version is that I can't simply host the webapp in a normal manner, so hosting it on a central machine and accessing it through that machine's web browser currently seems like the most feasible solution.

Comment: A web app needs but a forwarded http connection, so that does sound like a questionable claim!